# Proofs a logical form

Tags: proof-explanation

Let $\mathcal F$ be a non-empty family of sets with $A\in\mathcal F$.

$(a)$ Prove $A\subset\bigcup\mathcal F$

$(b)$ Prove $\cap\mathcal F\subset A$

$(c)$ Why was the assumption that $\mathcal F$ is nonempty needed?

Was it needed for both parts $(a)$ and $(b)$, or just one? 
If just one, which one?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I suppose if $A\in\mathscr F$, then it goes without saying that $\mathscr F$ is non-empty

Answer (score 0):

a) Prove ⊂⋃ℱ

I did Let x ∈ A then x ∈ F since A ∈ F. 
Since x ∈ F, it follows that x ⊂ UF. 
Since x ∈ A then A ⊂ UF.

Is it correct?

Comment: $x\in A$ and $A\in F$ means $x\in\cup F$, but it does not mean $x\in F$